# Mapping template folder in Django

Tags: python, django

I am not able to map html files from the directory, however i've followed all the instructions.

Following is my project urls.py:-

```
 from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
      # Uncomment the next two lines to enable the admin:
      # from django.contrib import admin
      # admin.autodiscover()
      urlpatterns = patterns('',
           url(r'^articles/', include('article.urls')),
 )
```

Views.py in app:-

```
      from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
      from article.models import Article

        def articles(request):
             return render_to_response('articles.html',{'articles':                 
                       Article.objects.all()})
         def article(request, article_id=1):
             return render_to_response('article.html',{'article':            
                       Article.objects.get(id=article_id)})
```

Urls.py in app:

```
      from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
      urlpatterns = patterns('', 
        url(r'^all/$', 'artilce.views.articles'),
        url(r'^get/(?P<article_id>\d+)/$', 'article.view.article'),
  )
```

Settings.py shows exact location of template folder as:-

```
       TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
              'C:\Python27\Scripts\django_test\article\templates',
```

Kindly advise. It shows article on 404 page but couldn't map.

Comment: Are you running the test server?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use unix-style forward slashes for your path, even on Windows. See the doc page here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/settings/#template-dirs

Comment: Thanks...you were right...I am regular windows user so missed that out. Really appreciate your help.